# How do I make $con available as a parameter of $Query?

Tags: php

I can get by with editing procedural PHP (just), but OOP is a different thing. So I'm not that experienced with what I'm doing here, but I'm trying my best...

I have a file called Quote.object.php containing the following:

```
        $Query = new DbQuery( "INSERT", "quotes", $array );
        $this->id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

mysqli_insert_id needs to be fed a DB connection parameter, but I'm not sure how to do it. There is another file called Mysql.handler.php containing the database connection variable - is there a way that I can make $con available as a parameter of $Query above?

```
class DbQuery extends DbConnectionInfo{
// file: includes/classes/MysqlQuery.php
// contains functions needed to perform queries on mysql database and functions for     necessary data processing for application
//      SELECT = new DbQuery("select", table,cols[$value]  ,where[$col=$value],order[$value],limit);
//      INSERT = new DbQuery("insert", table, data[$col=$value]);
//      UPDATE = new DbQuery("update", table, data[$col=$value],where[$col=$value],limit);

// set testing as true for SQL reports in page
var $results;
var $sql;

function __construct($mode,$table = '',$var1 = '',$var2 = '',$var3 = '',$var4='')
//connects to database according to info in DbConnectInfo, runs query, closes connection
{
$temp = '';
$con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass) or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database ' . (ENVIRONMENT == 'Development' ? mysqli_error() . "$this->user, $this->pass, $this->host" : ''));
mysqli_select_db($con,$this->db) or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database'  . (ENVIRONMENT == 'Development' ? mysqli_error() : ''));
```

I'm trying to get $con from DbQuery so I can put it into `mysqli_insert_id()`. I assume that's what I need? Is there a way to get $con from DbQuery and put into `mysqli_insert_id()`? Or do you need more information to know this?

***NB** I've tried to be concise in trying to show just relevant information, apologies if I've missed other helpful info.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining an object, so make $con a class variable, e.g.

```
function __construct() {
    $this->con = mysqli_connect(...);
    ^^^^^^^----store in object
}

function foo() {
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $this->con);
                                   ^^^^^^^^---retrieve from object
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Marc. I tried and tested what you said and ended up changing `$con` to `$this->con` and then `$this->id = mysqli_insert_id($Query->con);` - it seems to work so thank you very much!! :-)